# Setting background color instead of gradient for older browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a web page which has elements using css3 gradient. The thing is, if users browser does not support gradient I would like it to have a solid color. Is there a way to do that using css? I was thinking about simply setting `background-color` property, and then setting gradient with `!important` flag, but I would like to avoid using !important whenever possible.

Comment: Most of the browsers that don't support this and actually have a share of the market is IE, thus the best thing to do is to load an IE stylesheet.

Comment: @DragosRizescu you are right, the thing is however except for this single thing everything else is compatibile/doesn't matter (I use CSS3 for effects which are not necessary, but look nice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you just do `background-color:blue;` before the gradient it will show the background color in old browsers